# Software to draw/edit the Syntax of SQL statements

Tags: diagrams

Looking at the images [under *Syntax* here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065646).

[image]

It shows the syntax (grammar) in a visual way. Is there specialized software for creating and editing such diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tool for generating railroad diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org/7143467#7143467) on StackOverflow.

There is an [online railroad diagram generator](http://railroad.my28msec.com/rr/ui) which generates SVG diagrams from EBNF

[image: example railroad diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Some web searching for "syntax diagram generator" (and similar phrases) got me this: http://karmin.ch/ebnf/index

I've never used it but it looks like it will generate syntax diagrams. They won't look 100% like Oracle's but they should still be usable. I don't know what tool Oracles, uses. Probably some internal tool that they don't distribute.

Here's another one:

http://dotnet.jku.at/applications/Visualizer/

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite's railroad diagrams](https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/doc/sqlitesyntax.md) are rendered using a diagramming tool made by SQLite's author: [Pikchr](https://pikchr.org/).