# Program for creating language syntax/grammar "railroad" diagrams?

Tags: software-rec, syntax, diagrams, grammar

I'm looking for the program that JSON, SQLite and other projects are using to create the diagrams used for their language syntax, if there is a particular program.  All of the diagrams have a similar style, with partially curved connections or arrows indicating flow.

There are some differences, making me wonder if it's a single program or just generic graphing tools used for a particular style.

[image: JSON Digit]
[image: SQLite Select Statement]

Comment: The top one is from json.org and was drawn by Douglas Crockford using Visio. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/796824/477035 as in Chris W. Rea's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see by my edits to your question, the kind of *syntax diagram* you're referring to is also known as a **[railroad diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram)**. Wikipedia mentions a few tools under the "External Links" section, including:

- [EBNF Visualizer](http://dotnet.jku.at/applications/Visualizer/)
- [Ebnf2ps: Peter's Syntax Diagram Drawing Tool](https://github.com/FranklinChen/Ebnf2ps)
- [EBNF Parser & Syntax Diagram Renderer](http://karmin.ch/ebnf/index)
- [SQLite bubble-generator.tcl](http://www.sqlite.org/docsrc/finfo?name=art/syntax/bubble-generator.tcl)

See also these related Stack Exchange questions:

- Super User: [Software to draw/edit the Syntax of SQL statements](https://superuser.com/questions/353273/software-to-draw-edit-the-syntax-of-sql-statements)
- Stack Overflow: [Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org)
- Stack Overflow: [What is a good tool for creating railroad diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773371/what-is-a-good-tool-for-creating-railroad-diagrams)
- Stack Overflow: [What's the name for this type of flowchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269949/whats-the-name-for-this-type-of-flowchart)
- Stack Overflow: [Software for creating “Language Diagrams” structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126766/software-for-creating-language-diagrams-structures)
- Stack Overflow: [BNF notation to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292148/bnf-notation-to-svg)

Answer (score 0):

WAKING UP THE ZOMBIES!!!

I also found!

http://clapham.hydromatic.net/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.